# converting XML nodes to a dataframe

Tags: r, xml

I am working with an XML file and I managed to extract a set of nodes from it that I am interested in:

```
XMLData  <- xmlParse("MX_Test_K_Charge_2-6.xml")
XMLNodes <- getNodeSet(xx,"//Mono")
```

I get a set of nodes that look like this:

```
[[1]]
<Mono MonoisoMass="3333.7954" SumIntensity="31795.6617" AveragineMass="3334.7653">
  <Charged>
    <Match Chg="5" MoiM="3332.8416" avgMoiM="3332.7844" MoiMz="667.5756" calcMoiMz="667.56261" MabMz="667.7632" MabInt="5995" Dev="15.65" Scale="1.087"/>
    <Match Chg="6" MoiM="3332.7776" avgMoiM="3332.7768" MoiMz="556.4702" calcMoiMz="556.47006" MabMz="556.6372" MabInt="5554" Dev="2.02" Scale="0.999"/>
    <Match Chg="4" MoiM="3332.7775" avgMoiM="3332.7774" MoiMz="834.2016" calcMoiMz="834.20145" MabMz="834.4524" MabInt="5613" Dev="2.00" Scale="0.999"/>
    <Match Chg="3" MoiM="3332.7760" avgMoiM="3332.7765" MoiMz="1111.9326" calcMoiMz="1111.93284" MabMz="1112.2676" MabInt="5501" Dev="2.17" Scale="1.001"/>
    <Match Chg="2" MoiM="3332.7786" avgMoiM="3332.7770" MoiMz="1667.3966" calcMoiMz="1667.39562" MabMz="1667.8966" MabInt="5574" Dev="1.40" Scale="0.999"/>
  </Charged>
</Mono> 

[[2]]
<Mono MonoisoMass="2667.3004" SumIntensity="24359.4426" AveragineMass="2667.3000">
  <Charged>
    <Match Chg="2" MoiM="2666.2969" avgMoiM="2666.2968" MoiMz="1334.1557" calcMoiMz="1334.15581" MabMz="1334.6573" MabInt="5596" Dev="5.32" Scale="0.971"/>
    <Match Chg="3" MoiM="2666.2970" avgMoiM="2666.2969" MoiMz="889.7730" calcMoiMz="889.77296" MabMz="890.1073" MabInt="5482" Dev="7.28" Scale="0.971"/>
    <Match Chg="4" MoiM="2666.2733" avgMoiM="2666.2926" MoiMz="667.5756" calcMoiMz="667.58154" MabMz="667.8324" MabInt="4790" Dev="33.98" Scale="0.854"/>
    <Match Chg="5" MoiM="2666.2976" avgMoiM="2666.2976" MoiMz="534.2668" calcMoiMz="534.26669" MabMz="534.4674" MabInt="5437" Dev="7.52" Scale="0.970"/>
    <Match Chg="6" MoiM="2666.2977" avgMoiM="2666.2975" MoiMz="445.3902" calcMoiMz="445.39012" MabMz="445.5574" MabInt="5442" Dev="7.62" Scale="0.970"/>
  </Charged>
</Mono> 

[[3]]
<Mono MonoisoMass="2000.8526" SumIntensity="20204.6338" AveragineMass="1999.8456">
  <Charged>
    <Match Chg="6" MoiM="1999.8456" avgMoiM="1999.8451" MoiMz="334.3149" calcMoiMz="334.31481" MabMz="334.4820" MabInt="5115" Dev="6.90" Scale="0.954"/>
    <Match Chg="5" MoiM="1999.8456" avgMoiM="1999.8452" MoiMz="400.9764" calcMoiMz="400.97632" MabMz="401.1769" MabInt="5040" Dev="6.63" Scale="0.956"/>
    <Match Chg="4" MoiM="1999.8457" avgMoiM="1999.8452" MoiMz="500.9687" calcMoiMz="500.96858" MabMz="501.2194" MabInt="5014" Dev="6.88" Scale="0.954"/>
    <Match Chg="3" MoiM="1999.8453" avgMoiM="1999.8480" MoiMz="667.6224" calcMoiMz="667.62234" MabMz="667.9603" MabInt="4353" Dev="3.44" Scale="1.010"/>
    <Match Chg="2" MoiM="1999.8450" avgMoiM="1999.8447" MoiMz="1000.9298" calcMoiMz="1000.92988" MabMz="1001.4312" MabInt="5030" Dev="4.91" Scale="0.955"/>
  </Charged>
</Mono> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

now I would like to take this set of nodes and convert to a dataframe so that there are columns: MonoisoMass; SumIntensity; AveragineMass; present as attributes in parent node

present in the child node

I am sorry if the question was already asked but I find documentation of the XML package extremely complicated to understand. I would also appreciate if you could refer me to a tutorial or a book that explains working with XML file in R in an understandable way.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could improve your question. Please read [how to provide minimal reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit & improve it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(xml2)
mono <- dat %>% map(xml_find_all, "//Mono")
parent_dat <- mono %>% map(xml_attrs) %>% flatten %>% map(~t(.) %>% as_tibble)
child_dat <- mono %>% map(xml_find_all,"//Match") %>% map(xml_attrs) %>% map(~map_df(., ~t(.) %>% as_tibble))
map2_df(parent_dat, child_dat, cbind) %>% type_convert
```

which gives you:

```
   MonoisoMass SumIntensity AveragineMass Chg     MoiM  avgMoiM     MoiMz calcMoiMz     MabMz MabInt   Dev Scale
1     3333.795     31795.66      3334.765   5 3332.842 3332.784  667.5756  667.5626  667.7632   5995 15.65 1.087
2     3333.795     31795.66      3334.765   6 3332.778 3332.777  556.4702  556.4701  556.6372   5554  2.02 0.999
3     3333.795     31795.66      3334.765   4 3332.778 3332.777  834.2016  834.2015  834.4524   5613  2.00 0.999
4     3333.795     31795.66      3334.765   3 3332.776 3332.776 1111.9326 1111.9328 1112.2676   5501  2.17 1.001
5     3333.795     31795.66      3334.765   2 3332.779 3332.777 1667.3966 1667.3956 1667.8966   5574  1.40 0.999
6     2667.300     24359.44      2667.300   2 2666.297 2666.297 1334.1557 1334.1558 1334.6573   5596  5.32 0.971
7     2667.300     24359.44      2667.300   3 2666.297 2666.297  889.7730  889.7730  890.1073   5482  7.28 0.971
8     2667.300     24359.44      2667.300   4 2666.273 2666.293  667.5756  667.5815  667.8324   4790 33.98 0.854
9     2667.300     24359.44      2667.300   5 2666.298 2666.298  534.2668  534.2667  534.4674   5437  7.52 0.970
10    2667.300     24359.44      2667.300   6 2666.298 2666.298  445.3902  445.3901  445.5574   5442  7.62 0.970
```

Assuming your data looks as follows:

```
txt1 <- '<Mono MonoisoMass="3333.7954" SumIntensity="31795.6617" AveragineMass="3334.7653">
  <Charged>
    <Match Chg="5" MoiM="3332.8416" avgMoiM="3332.7844" MoiMz="667.5756" calcMoiMz="667.56261" MabMz="667.7632" MabInt="5995" Dev="15.65" Scale="1.087"/>
    <Match Chg="6" MoiM="3332.7776" avgMoiM="3332.7768" MoiMz="556.4702" calcMoiMz="556.47006" MabMz="556.6372" MabInt="5554" Dev="2.02" Scale="0.999"/>
    <Match Chg="4" MoiM="3332.7775" avgMoiM="3332.7774" MoiMz="834.2016" calcMoiMz="834.20145" MabMz="834.4524" MabInt="5613" Dev="2.00" Scale="0.999"/>
    <Match Chg="3" MoiM="3332.7760" avgMoiM="3332.7765" MoiMz="1111.9326" calcMoiMz="1111.93284" MabMz="1112.2676" MabInt="5501" Dev="2.17" Scale="1.001"/>
    <Match Chg="2" MoiM="3332.7786" avgMoiM="3332.7770" MoiMz="1667.3966" calcMoiMz="1667.39562" MabMz="1667.8966" MabInt="5574" Dev="1.40" Scale="0.999"/>
  </Charged>
</Mono> '

txt2 <- '<Mono MonoisoMass="2667.3004" SumIntensity="24359.4426" AveragineMass="2667.3000">
  <Charged>
<Match Chg="2" MoiM="2666.2969" avgMoiM="2666.2968" MoiMz="1334.1557" calcMoiMz="1334.15581" MabMz="1334.6573" MabInt="5596" Dev="5.32" Scale="0.971"/>
<Match Chg="3" MoiM="2666.2970" avgMoiM="2666.2969" MoiMz="889.7730" calcMoiMz="889.77296" MabMz="890.1073" MabInt="5482" Dev="7.28" Scale="0.971"/>
<Match Chg="4" MoiM="2666.2733" avgMoiM="2666.2926" MoiMz="667.5756" calcMoiMz="667.58154" MabMz="667.8324" MabInt="4790" Dev="33.98" Scale="0.854"/>
<Match Chg="5" MoiM="2666.2976" avgMoiM="2666.2976" MoiMz="534.2668" calcMoiMz="534.26669" MabMz="534.4674" MabInt="5437" Dev="7.52" Scale="0.970"/>
<Match Chg="6" MoiM="2666.2977" avgMoiM="2666.2975" MoiMz="445.3902" calcMoiMz="445.39012" MabMz="445.5574" MabInt="5442" Dev="7.62" Scale="0.970"/>
</Charged>
</Mono> '



dat <- map(list(txt1, txt2), read_xml)
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You ave produced a table that contains columns: MonoisoMass SumIntensity AveragineMass, I would also like data from the charge node added so the table should also contain columns called Chg; MoiM; avgMoiM; MoiMz; calcMoiMz; MabMz; MabInt; Dev; Scale